# Issue with NameError: name 'vor' is not defined

Tags: python

I am using the code from https://github.com/ReScience-Archives/Rougier-2017/tree/master/code

When I run it, I get an error :

```
for region in vor.filtered_regions:
NameError: name 'vor' is not defined
```

This is the relevant code in the stippler.py file:

**stippler.py**

```
import tqdm
import voronoi
import os.path
import scipy.misc
import scipy.ndimage
import numpy as np

---- ---
# Plot voronoi regions if you want
for region in vor.filtered_regions:
    vertices = vor.vertices[region, :]
    ax.plot(vertices[:, 0], vertices[:, 1], linewidth=.5, color='.5' )
```

This is the code in the imported file voronoi.py

**voronoi.py**

```
    import numpy as np
    import scipy.spatial

    def rasterize(V):
        n = len(V)
        X, Y = V[:, 0], V[:, 1]
        ymin = int(np.ceil(Y.min()))
        ymax = int(np.floor(Y.max()))
        #ymin = int(np.round(Y.min()))
        #ymax = int(np.round(Y.max()))
        P = []
        for y in range(ymin, ymax+1):
            segments = []
            for i in range(n):
                index1, index2 = (i-1) % n, i
                y1, y2 = Y[index1], Y[index2]
                x1, x2 = X[index1], X[index2]
                if y1 > y2:
                    y1, y2 = y2, y1
                    x1, x2 = x2, x1
                elif y1 == y2:
                    continue
                if (y1 <= y < y2) or (y == ymax and y1 < y <= y2):
                    segments.append((y-y1) * (x2-x1) / (y2-y1) + x1)

            segments.sort()
            for i in range(0, (2*(len(segments)//2)), 2):
                x1 = int(np.ceil(segments[i]))
                x2 = int(np.floor(segments[i+1]))
                # x1 = int(np.round(segments[i]))
                # x2 = int(np.round(segments[i+1]))
                P.extend([[x, y] for x in range(x1, x2+1)])
        if not len(P):
            return V
        return np.array(P)


    def rasterize_outline(V):
        n = len(V)
        X, Y = V[:, 0], V[:, 1]
        ymin = int(np.ceil(Y.min()))
        ymax = int(np.floor(Y.max()))
        points = np.zeros((2+(ymax-ymin)*2, 3), dtype=int)
        index = 0
        for y in range(ymin, ymax+1):
            segments = []
            for i in range(n):
                index1, index2 = (i-1) % n , i
                y1, y2 = Y[index1], Y[index2]
                x1, x2 = X[index1], X[index2]
                if y1 > y2:
                    y1, y2 = y2, y1
                    x1, x2 = x2, x1
                elif y1 == y2:
                    continue
                if (y1 <= y < y2) or (y == ymax and y1 < y <= y2):
                    segments.append((y-y1) * (x2-x1) / (y2-y1) + x1)
            segments.sort()
            for i in range(0, (2*(len(segments)//2)), 2):
                x1 = int(np.ceil(segments[i]))
                x2 = int(np.ceil(segments[i+1]))
                points[index] = x1, x2, y
                index += 1
        return points[:index]


    def weighted_centroid_outline(V, P, Q):
        O = rasterize_outline(V)
        X1, X2, Y = O[:,0], O[:,1], O[:,2]

        Y = np.minimum(Y, P.shape[0]-1)
        X1 = np.minimum(X1, P.shape[1]-1)
        X2 = np.minimum(X2, P.shape[1]-1)

        d = (P[Y,X2]-P[Y,X1]).sum()
        x = ((X2*P[Y,X2] - Q[Y,X2]) - (X1*P[Y,X1] - Q[Y,X1])).sum()
        y = (Y * (P[Y,X2] - P[Y,X1])).sum()
        if d:
            return [x/d, y/d]
        return [x, y]



    def uniform_centroid(V):
        """
        Given an ordered set of vertices V describing a polygon,
        returns the uniform surface centroid.

        See http://paulbourke.net/geometry/polygonmesh/
        """
        A = 0
        Cx = 0
        Cy = 0
        for i in range(len(V)-1):
            s = (V[i, 0]*V[i+1, 1] - V[i+1, 0]*V[i, 1])
            A += s
            Cx += (V[i, 0] + V[i+1, 0]) * s
            Cy += (V[i, 1] + V[i+1, 1]) * s
        Cx /= 3*A
        Cy /= 3*A
        return [Cx, Cy]


    def weighted_centroid(V, D):
        P = rasterize(V)
        Pi = P.astype(int)
        Pi[:, 0] = np.minimum(Pi[:, 0], D.shape[1]-1)
        Pi[:, 1] = np.minimum(Pi[:, 1], D.shape[0]-1)
        D = D[Pi[:, 1], Pi[:, 0]].reshape(len(Pi), 1)
        return ((P*D)).sum(axis=0) / D.sum()

    def in_box(points, bbox):
        return np.logical_and(
            np.logical_and(bbox[0] <= points[:, 0], points[:, 0] <= bbox[1]),
            np.logical_and(bbox[2] <= points[:, 1], points[:, 1] <= bbox[3]))


    def voronoi(points, bbox):
        i = in_box(points, bbox)
        points_center = points[i, :]
        points_left = np.copy(points_center)
        points_left[:, 0] = bbox[0] - (points_left[:, 0] - bbox[0])
        points_right = np.copy(points_center)
        points_right[:, 0] = bbox[1] + (bbox[1] - points_right[:, 0])
        points_down = np.copy(points_center)
        points_down[:, 1] = bbox[2] - (points_down[:, 1] - bbox[2])
        points_up = np.copy(points_center)
        points_up[:, 1] = bbox[3] + (bbox[3] - points_up[:, 1])
        points = np.append(points_center,
                           np.append(np.append(points_left, points_right, axis=0),
                                     np.append(points_down, points_up, axis=0),
                                     axis=0), axis=0)
        # Compute Voronoi
        vor = scipy.spatial.Voronoi(points)

        # Filter regions
        epsilon = 0.1
        regions = []
        for region in vor.regions:
            flag = True
            for index in region:
                if index == -1:
                    flag = False
                    break
                else:
                    x = vor.vertices[index, 0]
                    y = vor.vertices[index, 1]
                    if not(bbox[0]-epsilon <= x <= bbox[1]+epsilon and
                           bbox[2]-epsilon <= y <= bbox[3]+epsilon):
                        flag = False
                        break
            if region != [] and flag:
                regions.append(region)
        vor.filtered_points = points_center
        vor.filtered_regions = regions
        return vor


    def centroids(points, density, density_P=None, density_Q=None):
        """
        Given a set of point and a density array, return the set of weighted
        centroids.
        """

        X, Y = points[:,0], points[:, 1]
        # You must ensure:
        #   0 < X.min() < X.max() < density.shape[0]
        #   0 < Y.min() < Y.max() < density.shape[1]

        xmin, xmax = 0, density.shape[1]
        ymin, ymax = 0, density.shape[0]
        bbox = np.array([xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax])
        vor = voronoi(points, bbox)
        regions = vor.filtered_regions
        centroids = []
        for region in regions:
            vertices = vor.vertices[region + [region[0]], :]
            # vertices = vor.filtered_points[region + [region[0]], :]

            # Full version from all the points
            # centroid = weighted_centroid(vertices, density)

            # Optimized version from only the outline
            centroid = weighted_centroid_outline(vertices, density_P, density_Q)

            centroids.append(centroid)
        return regions, np.array(centroids)
```

I am new to python so I am unsure what is causing the error besides knowing it has to do with vor not being defined or maybe an importing issue?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the variable "vor" is not defined before you access it.

Answer (score 0):

This is entirely too much code to post, you need to trim it down to just show a minimum complete viable example. With that being said in `stippler.py` you import `voronoi` which is a function which returns `vor` according to `voronoi.py`. Nowhere in `stippler.py` do you call on that function to return `vor` which is what you want. You also have the problem that your script has the same name as your function so you would probably need to do something like the following in order to call the function:

```
from voronoi import voronoi

# feed your function the relevant inputs
vor = voronoi(points, bbox)

# continue your code here
```

Answer (score 0):

That code [had been commented out in the original code](https://github.com/ReScience-Archives/Rougier-2017/blob/0637d15ddac808e66c7943dfd2b301ab8cde78a5/code/stippler.py#L253-L256), presumably because it doesn't work anymore (as you've found out).

The `vor` object with a `filtered_regions` attribute is generated by the [`voronoi.voronoi()`](https://github.com/ReScience-Archives/Rougier-2017/blob/0637d15ddac808e66c7943dfd2b301ab8cde78a5/code/voronoi.py#L174) function, but it doesn't appear to be called by the current code anymore.

Maybe just

```
vor = voronoi.voronoi(points, bbox)
```

before that segment might fix it.